# How to correctly use = wp_enqueue_style with a CDN in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, cdn

**My current code:**

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'script-css', plugins_url( 'script/myscript.js', __FILE__ ));
```

**My goal:**
Instead of loading the file from the plugins directory, I want to load above script file from http://mycloudfronturl.net/myscript.js

But somehow I am messing with either the quotes or while replacing the plugins_url. I am not a hard code php coder, so can someone tell me what to do please?

Comment: how are you including external file?

Answer (score 4):

Use enqueue_script instead.
Sample example:

```
wp_register_script('some_script', 'http://anywhereyouwant.com');
wp_enqueue_script('some_script');
```

Comment: Your comment doesn't help. What do i about the "plugins_url()" part in my code???

If I change my code to:
wp_enqueue_style( 'script-css', 'http://mycloudfronturl.net/myscript.js', FILE ));

It breaks my page and simply shows a blank white page.

Comment: You shoud use wp_enqueue_style for enqueing styles and wp_enqueue_script for enqueing scripts. In your example you trying to enque style and give as second param path to script file. Just make shure that your code is look like this: wp_enqueue_script( 'script-css', 'http://mycloudfronturl.net/myscript.js');